# Replace a word in column that have much content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to know how can i change a word in a column TEXT have much words. 
for example i have this

```
|id|             content             |
| 1| my name is alpha root i like .. |
| 2| i need your help am alpha root  |
| 3| Today i was with alpha root     |
```

I want a query that can help me to change `alpha` to `beta` in content and keep other things.
to become like that

```
|id|             content             |
| 1| my name is beta root i like ..  |
| 2| i need your help am beta root   |
| 3| Today i was with beta root      |
```

I have researched a lot but no results

Comment: Did you try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace ?

Comment: Why research "much"? Your first and ONLY stop for things like this should be the mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Please backup your data first, in case you change partial words e.g. `alphabet` to `betabet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'alpha', 'beta')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%alpha%'
```

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1):

Use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
UPDATE table SET content = REPLACE(content, 'alpha', 'beta')
```

Answer (score 1):

use str_replace("alpha","beta","your string")

it will result in changes string for more on these http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: That would be **very** inefficient. MySQL can do that for you.

Comment: yes, i thought he is asking for string, didn't read the full question

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET content = REPLACE(content, 'alpha', 'beta')
WHERE INSTR(content, 'alpha')>0
```